# How to update this jQuery script to work with latest jQuery version 3.3.1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation

I'm trying to use magic line menu on a project that I am working on. The jQuery script works fine with jquery 2.1.4. What do I need to update to get the code below to work with the latest version of jQuery 3.3.1?

Or if there is any recent magic line plugin that works with latest jQuery version please recommend it.

I am trying to use this jQuery function on a WordPress website and it does not seem to work. In a normal HTML template also it does not work when the latest version of jquery is loaded but works fine with an older version of jquery.

The code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        var nav_wrap = $(".sliding-menu"),
        elem_width,
        elem_left_offset,
        elem_parent,
        slider_line;

    $(window).load(function(){

        nav_wrap.each(function(){
            $(this).append('<li class="sliding-line"></li>');

            var start_elem_width = 0;
            var start_elem_offset = 0;
            var active_elem = $(this).find(".active");

            if(active_elem.length){
                start_elem_width = active_elem.outerWidth();
                start_elem_offset = active_elem.position().left;
            }

            $(this).find(".sliding-line").css({
                "width": start_elem_width + "px",
                "left": start_elem_offset + "px"
            })
            .data("width", start_elem_width)
            .data("left", start_elem_offset);
        });

    });

    nav_wrap.find("li a").hover(function(){

        elem_parent = $(this).parent();
        elem_width = elem_parent.outerWidth();
        elem_left_offset = $(this).position().left;
        slider_line = elem_parent.siblings(".sliding-line");
        slider_line.stop().animate({
            "width": elem_width + "px",
            "left": elem_left_offset + "px"
        });

    }, function(){

        slider_line.stop().animate({
            "width": slider_line.data("width") + "px",
            "left": slider_line.data("left") + "px"
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: Can you narrow it down for us? What doesn't work exactly? Does it render wrongly, or does it all just "not work"? This may be too broad here, and is probably best raised with the developer.

Comment: Useful reading: questions on Stack Overflow need an [mcve].

Comment: thank you for the reply @halfer. The plugin does not work when the latest version of jquery loaded. Any code there that does not work with the latest version of jquery?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. The code is not outdated there for no need to edit the functions. I have added the following code to the JS file:

jQuery(document).ready( function($){

and now it is working well on WordPress.